# Mistakenly set a bounty

Tags: support, status-completed, bounties

I know this is a very old question but I want to know another thing

If I flag my question to moderator then is it possible that they cancel my bounty and return back my reputation?

I really want my points back :( because I have settled it mistakenly

Comment: Which question did you set the bounty on?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1321399/khan?tab=bounties&sort=active

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Also the status of [this same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154812/187824) is completed

Comment: Exactly this one :)

Comment: @khan: Your bounty is canceled now :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am facing the punishment from last 6 months.Dont you think its enough :( please reopen my account as now it wont happen again and ill take care about all these things in future.Please reopen my account

Comment: @khan: Do you understand why you were suspended?

Comment: I am apologizing and I promise that Ill never break the rules again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey please :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the bounty mistakenly, you should flag it to moderators and explain the situation. But it does not guarantee that your bounty will be canceled because it totally depends on moderators. They will decide to cancel it or no.

From [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/187824)

> #### Can I cancel my bounty?
>
> No. Once you start a bounty, you cannot cancel it.
>
> If you feel there are exceptional circumstances, flag the question for
> moderator attention to explain the situation.